# how to choose positive symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

What are the ways to find a positive symmetric matrix $P$ such that

$
A^{T}P+PA=-Q$

where $Q$ is also positive symmetric matrix, $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & I_{n}\\
-K_{v} & -K_{p}
\end{array}\right]_{2n\times2n}$, $K_{v}=k_{v}I_{n}$, and $K_{p}=k_{p}I_{n}$? Here $I_n$ stands for $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you're asking. Please fix your typesetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $PA = (A^TP)^T$ and, denoting the blocks of $P$ as $P_{ij}$ for $i=1,2$, $j = 1,2$,
$$A^TP = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -K_v \\ {\rm I}_n & -K_p \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} P_{11} & P_{12} \\ P_{12}^T & P_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -K_v P_{12}^T & -K_v P_{22} \\ P_{11} - K_p P_{12}^T & P_{12} - K_p P_{22} \end{bmatrix}.$$

So,
$$-Q = A^TP + PA = A^TP + (A^TP)^T = \begin{bmatrix} -k_v (P_{12} + P_{12}^T) & P_{11} - k_p P_{12} - k_v P_{22} \\ P_{11} - k_p P_{12}^T - k_v P_{22} & P_{12} + P_{12}^T - 2k_p P_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

Denoting blocks of $Q$ as we did with $P$, we get:

1. $P_{12} + P_{12}^T = k_v^{-1} Q_{11}$ from the top left block;
2. $P_{22} =  k_p^{-1}(k_v^{-1}Q_{11} + Q_{22})$, from the bottom right block;
3. $P_{11} = 2^{-1}(k_p k_v^{-1} Q_{11} - (Q_{12} + Q_{12}^T)) + k_v k_p^{-1}(k_v^{-1}Q_{11} + Q_{22})$, from the sum the nondiagonal blocks;
4. Get $P_{12}$ from any of the nondiagonal blocks.

It remains to show/check that $P$ is positive definite.